# AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "application" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</application>"

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest, manifest

I'm trying to run my android app but I'm getting the following error

> Resource Path Location Type Parser exception for
>   /TheDatingNetwork/AndroidManifest.xml: The element type "application"
>   must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
>   TheDatingNetwork      line 1 Android ADT Problem

Can somebody write me the 'correct' version of it? Thanks.

This is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Image"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image" >
        </activity>
       </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: remove  </activity> on top of </application> tag

Answer (score 1):

there is one `</activity>` to much at the end:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
            android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Image"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image" >
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have mismatching `</activity>` tag before `</application>`.

Answer (score 0):

see the comment

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="20" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" android:required="false"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Splashscreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.creativedigitals.easywebapp.Image"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_image" >
    </activity>
   </activity>//remove this extra closing tag 
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have inserted a extra `</activity>`, remove `</activity>` before `</application>` tag.